# An inequality satisfied by the circumradius and inradius of a right triangle

Tags: geometry, inequality, triangles, circles, geometric-inequalities

This should be trivial, but I am unable to show that $R \geq (1+\sqrt{2})r$ for a right triangle. Where $R$ is the circumradius and $r$ is the inradius of a right triangle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $a,b,c$ be the sides of the triangle ($c$ is the hypotenuse). Then the circumradius is $c/2$, while The inradius has the formula $$r = \frac{2\Delta}{P}$$ where $\Delta$ is the area and $P$ is the perimeter. So, we have $$r = \frac{ab}{a+b+c}$$ for a right triangle. Now, we want to show that $(1+\sqrt{2})\frac{ab}{a+b+c} \leq (c/2)$, or 
$$
(2+2\sqrt{2}) ab \leq c(a+b+c) \hspace{2in} (1)
$$

Now, by AM-GM, $c=\sqrt{a^2+b^2} \geq \sqrt{2ab}$, and $a+b \geq 2 \sqrt{ab}$. Plugging in these inequalities, you can verify $(1)$.

Comment: @J.M. corrected, thanks!

Comment: Okay, I gave a +1 for the algebraic approach. :)

Answer (score 3):

First, note that for any right triangle with legs $a$ and $b$ and hypotenuse $c$, $r=\frac{1}{2}(a+b-c)$.

You should be able to convince yourself that, for a given hypotenuse length $c$ (and hence a given circumradius, since the circumcenter of any right triangle is the midpoint of the hypotenuse), the inradius is maximized when the right triangle is isosceles, so $a=b$.  For convenience (all such triangles are similar), let $c=2$ so that $a=b=\sqrt{2}$ and $R=1$.  Now, $r=\frac{1}{2}(a+b-c)=\frac{1}{2}(2\sqrt{2}-2)=\sqrt{2}-1$, so $(1+\sqrt{2})r=(1+\sqrt{2})(\sqrt{2}-1)=1=R$.  That is, in the case where $r$ is maximal, equality holds for your inequality.  So, for all right triangles, $R\ge(1+\sqrt{2})r$.

Comment: Can you show why the inradius is maximized when the triangle is isosceles? I know intuitively it is true, but how would one prove it?

Comment: @picakhu: Fix $c$ and let $a$ vary in the interval $(0,c)$.  From the Pythagorean Theorem, $b=\sqrt{c^2-a^2}$; $r=\frac{1}{2}(a+b-c)$ so as a function of $a$, $r(a)=\frac{1}{2}(a+\sqrt{c^2-a^2}-c)$.  Take the derivative and look for sign changes.  The only sign change in the derivative occurs when $a=\frac{c}{\sqrt{2}}$, which makes the triangle isosceles.

Comment: @picakhu: Less formally, for a fixed $c$, as $a\to0$ or alternately $b\to0$, $r\to0$.  $r$ is positive between those extremes, so there is a maximum.  The problem is symmetric with swapping $a$ and $b$, so the maximum should be exactly between those extremes, so when $a=b$.

Comment: ...and I upvoted this for the geometric way of looking at the problem.